# unable to restore .net application in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core-2.0

net core application in asp.net webapi. I am trying to deploy the solution in ubuntu. Below is my solution.
https://github.com/NiranjanAbb/TestRest.

I have insalled dotnetcore as

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.1
```

but I have used visual studio 2017 with dot net core 2.0

I started with below steps.

```
cd ~/source
git clone https://github.com/NiranjanAbb/TestRest.git
dotnet restore
```

Whenever I try to restore I am getting below error.

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery 2.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery 2.0.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) [/home/niranjan/source/TestRest/TestRest.sln]
```

Below is my .csproj file code.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Below I have attached screenshot of the error also.

[image]

I am new to the ubuntu environment and asp.net core as well. Can someone help me to figure out the root cause of this issue?

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try changing the framework settings to ".netstandard2.0" in .csproj file

Comment: Thanks. Also i installed dot net as sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.1. Should i upgrade it to 2.0?

Comment: I've only worked with CentOS  distro. And only used 2.0. You can try that as well

Comment: have you tried a `dotnet new mvc`?

Comment: No. I created webapi project. should i run  dotnet new mvc?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole: I assume that this issue is because of version of SDK. you're project is supported with SDK 2.0 and you're trying to build it on version 1.0.1. try to install 2.0 moreover, the project you put on github doesn't have any package reference recheck it.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah even I have noticed there is no package reference. How can I add packages in SDK?

Comment: I added core 2.0 and now issue with package reference. May I know how can I add those?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole: which package reference error are you getting?

Comment: Many errors I am getting. For example anti forgery error

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole: Hope that you have visited [Prerequisites for .NET Core on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x) and do not try to run your application first, just try run [hello world application](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxredhat) to assure that your basic setup is running, then try to run your project.

Comment: I understood but what I am trying to understand is I have downloaded core 2.0 in Ubuntu terminal. So this packages needs to be added in visual studio itself?

Comment: I have referred sample code at https://github.com/allebb/lk2.git. Here I can see under dependencies many packages installed. So like this how can I install packages to my webapi2 core project in visual studio project?